# ArrayList : Picking alternate elements

Tags: arraylist

I have a use case where I need to pick elements with alternate index :
for ex : list is having <10, 1, 20, 2, 30, 3, 40, 4>
The result should be :
10, 20
1, 3
30, 40
3, 4

Any suggestion ?

I could get the following :

10, 1
20, 2
30, 3
40, 4

Comment: if statement will do the job

Answer (score 0):

In c# something like this:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 10, 1, 20, 2, 30, 3, 40, 4 }

if (array1==array)
{
array1={10, 20 1, 3 30, 40 3, 4};
}
```